# Managing window messages for CEF client area in a popup window

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, chromium-embedded

I am developing an application on C++ using raw WinAPI, that uses CEF 3 for showing UI. The problem is that this UI is nested in a popup window (with no title bar and Close/Minimize buttons). So I want to make some client area to act like a caption, that user can drag and move window.

The easiest solution is subclassing CEF windows and "preprocessing" WM_NCHITTEST message, passing it to parent window (returning HTTRANSPARENT), and in parent window manage window-moving messages (return HTCAPTION on WM_NCHITTEST, do some stuff on WM_MOVE, WM_PAINT and other messages). This works if I manually do CEF message loop calling CefDoMessageLoopWork, but this takes all CPU resources.

Using multithreaded CEF message loop would be a solution, but this technique doesn't work.

So, the question is: how can I make clien area act like a caption using multithreaded CEF message loop as it uses a lot less resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to resolve my problem.
Initial message loop was something like this

```
if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE))
{
    GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 );
    TranlateMessage( &msg );
    DispatchMessage( &msg );
}
else 
{
    CefDoMessageLoopWork();
}
```

however it seems to be ok to call CefDoMessageLoopWork() just before main message processing, something like this:

```
if(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
{
    CefDoMessageLoopWork();
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

In this case CPU usage is OK;